# Cakephp 2.x get message { "name": "The request has been black-holed", "url": "\/rest_sms_boxs.json" } in Restfull api

Tags: rest, cakephp, blackhole

I write a controller and it contain multi POST action but whene i post data to these actions my response is :

> { "name": "The request has been black-holed", "url": "/rest_sms_boxs.json" }

Now how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the security mode.

Try in your controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() 
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('your_method');
}
```

Comment: Disable your security component and show your controller please